# Symmetry in Bayesian Hypothesis testing

Tags: bayesian, hypothesis-testing, symmetry

Let two hypothesis be:

$H_0: \rm PMF(\mu)$ with prior $(1-p)$ and

$H_1: \rm PMF(\sigma)$ with prior $p$.

Is it true that the probability of total error $ \Big( P_e= \rm type \:I \: error + type \: II \: error \Big)$ is *invariant* to swapping the priors? i-e for $H_0$ with prior $p$ and $H_1$ with prior $(1-p)$.

Comment: You mean you have a variable $X$ with $P(X = \mu) = 1-p$ and $P(X = \sigma) = p$?  And what do you mean by "total correct decisions"?

Comment: $\mu$ is a parameter of the distribution and not the realization. From total correct decisions= 1 - probability of total error.
Sorry for cofusion, I am editing my question.